# Can a Regex capture multiple similar pattern in a text block?

Tags: regex, powershell

I'm trying to extract specific words from text blocks. The blocks themselves look like that.

```
soundeffect = {
    name = event_ship_explosion
    sounds = {
        sound = event_ship_explosion
    }  
    volume = 0.2
    max_audible = 1
    max_audible_behaviour = fail
}

soundeffect = {
    name = event_ship_bridge
    sounds = {
        sound = event_ship_bridge
        sound = event_ship_bridge_02
        sound = event_ship_bridge_03
    }  
    volume = 0.3
    max_audible = 1
    max_audible_behaviour = fail        
}
```

They are quite similar but the main difference is that inside a `sounds` block, there can be multiple instance of `sound`. Whether there is a single or multiple instance of `sound`, I want to be able to extract all of them.

Basically, for each `soundeffect` blocks, I want to extract a pair of words containing what's on the right of `name =`  and what's on the right of `sound =`  (Multiple time, if applicable).

I came up with this RegEx so far and when testing it (on websites like https://regex101.com/r/MgaLZN/1) it seems to be working as it shows that the `Sound` named capturing group has 3 matches.
[image: Regex101 result]

The RegEx: `name\s*=\s*(?<Group>\w+)\s*sounds\s*=\s*{\s*(?>sound\s*=\s*(?<Sound>\w+)\s*)+}`

However, when using PowerShell, only the last instance of what's to the right of `sound =`  is retained. The previous matches are overridden. To transform all of that in an array of objects that I can then exploit (Using `ConvertFrom-Text` - https://github.com/jdhitsolutions/PSScriptTools/blob/master/docs/ConvertFrom-Text.md).
If you take the second `soundeffect` block, this is the result I get:

```
Group                                 Sound
-----                                 -----
event_ship_bridge                     event_ship_bridge_03
```

When I'm looking for something like that instead:

```
Group                                 Sound
-----                                 -----
event_ship_bridge                     @(event_ship_bridge, event_ship_bridge_02, event_ship_bridge_03}
```

I'm finally wondering if what I want to do is even possible with RegEx so I'm interested by all inputs you can give me. :)

Edit: here's the PowerShell code I'm using at the moment:

```
$Text | Select-String -Pattern $Regex -AllMatches | ForEach-Object {
    [string]$GroupName = $_.Matches.Groups[$Regex.GroupNumberFromName("Group")] | % { $_.Value }
    [string]$SoundName = $_.Matches.Groups[$Regex.GroupNumberFromName("Sound")] | % { $_.Value }

}

$GroupName
$SoundName
```

Which returns the following result as if the `-AllMatches` parameter was not respected.

```
event_ship_explosion
event_ship_explosion
```

Comment: "However, when using PowerShell, only the last instance of what's to the right of sound =  is retained.".    Reading this could mean an error in your PowerShell script, but you did not post that part....

Comment: Maybe when you see this https://regex101.com/r/BWS7d3/1 you do get another idea. I missed the fact that you also need the `name` from the soundeffect.

Comment: @Luuk: I have added the PowerShell code I'm using to test the Regex. I'm also feeding the text block and the Regex to the `ConvertFrom-Text` cmdlet with similar result.
Also, using your shared RegEx gives me the same result with the above PowerShell code. Only the first sound is kept (event_ship_explosion) and then, no other matches are returned.

Comment: If you want to get multiple matches and "glue" these to a successfull match of the `name`-part this can be done by use of the [`\G` anchor](https://www.regular-expressions.info/continue.html). No idea if it is supported by powershell. See [this demo at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/ZRI3hb/1) on how it's working. I just reordered your current pattern and split into an alternation for chaining.

Comment: Thanks @bobblebubble. I will check if PowerShell supports that or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There seems to be three problems in your PowerShell code.

1. Since there are multiple matches, you need another loop to go through all of them.
2. The "Sound" group has multiple captures, so you need to look at the `Captures` member to retrieve them all.
3. You're writing the results to variables rather than returning them. The variables will of course get overwritten in every iteration of the loop, so reading them outside the loop will only give you the last value.

Try something like this:

```powershell
PS > $Text | Select-String -Pattern $Regex -AllMatches | ForEach-Object { $_.Matches } | ForEach-Object {
>>     [pscustomobject]@{
>>         GroupName = $_.Groups[$Regex.GroupNumberFromName("Group")].Value
>>         SoundName = $_.Groups[$Regex.GroupNumberFromName("Sound")].Captures.Value
>>     }
>> }
>>

GroupName            SoundName
---------            ---------
event_ship_explosion event_ship_explosion
event_ship_bridge    {event_ship_bridge, event_ship_bridge_02, event_ship_bridge_03}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. The problem was in fact from the beginning a PowerShell problem rather than one with RegEx.
I tried to change that code at one point but I was not successful in getting the result you did so I was thinking the RegEx was the issue.

Answer (score 0):

A slightly different approach (I am pretty new to powershell):

```
$txt = Get-Content('./soundeffect.txt')

$txt | 
   select-String -Pattern "name =.*|sound =.*" | 
   ForEach-Object { $a = $_.Line.Trim().Split("="); 
                    if($a[0].Trim() -eq "name") { $soundeffect=$a[1].Trim() }
                    if($a[0].Trim() -eq "sound") { 
                       $sound=$a[1].Trim() 
                       "$soundeffect,  $sound"
                       }
                    $sound = ""
                  }
```

output:

```
event_ship_explosion,  event_ship_explosion
event_ship_bridge,  event_ship_bridge
event_ship_bridge,  event_ship_bridge_02
event_ship_bridge,  event_ship_bridge_03
```

Comment: Thanks for the proposal. However, working with objects like offered by @jkiiski better fits what I'm looking for and is more easy.